# Fatal error: Function name must be a string in after updating wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I just updated wordpress to newest version. And this happened on my site. Every site I loaded showed this error message:

```
Fatal error:
Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in /home/penzionhaji.cz/penzionhaji.cz/wp-content/themes/enfold/framework/php/class-style-generator.php:119
Stack trace:
#0 /home/penzionhaji.cz/penzionhaji.cz/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): avia_style_generator->create_styles('')
#1 /home/penzionhaji.cz/penzionhaji.cz/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#2 /home/penzionhaji.cz/penzionhaji.cz/wp-includes/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#3 /home/penzionhaji.cz/penzionhaji.cz/wp-includes/general-template.php(3009): do_action('wp_head')
#4 /home/penzionhaji.cz/penzionhaji.cz/wp-content/themes/enfold/header.php(52): wp_head()
#5 /home/penzionhaji.cz/penzionhaji.cz/wp-includes/template.php(730): require_once('/home/penzionha...')
#6 /home/penzionhaji.cz/penzionhaji.cz/wp-includes/template.php(676): load_template('/home/penzionha...', true, Array)
#7 /home/penzionhaji.cz/penzionhaji.cz/wp-includes/general-template.php(48): locate_template(Array, true, true, Array)
#8  in /home/penzionhaji.cz/penzionhaji.cz/wp-content/themes/enfold/framework/php/class-style-generator.php on line 119
```

It seems to be a problem with using a particular template. I tried to downgrade WordPress version, but it caused another error.